# Keep previous information when running an executable from command lines

Tags: linux, window

In Windows when I run an executalbe from command line, for example, `abc.exe -i abc.bmp >output.txt`, all the output of the program will be put in the text file. However, all the previous contents in the text file will also be destroyed. So if I run the following commands sequentially,

```
abc.exe -i abc.bmp >output.txt

abc.exe -i def.bmp >output.txt
```

Only the information when running the second file will be kept in output.txt. So my question is how I can also keep the previous information in the txt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `>>` to append to a file.

```
abc.exe -i abc.bmp >output.txt

abc.exe -i def.bmp >>output.txt
```

The first line will create or clear the file. The second line will append to it.

Comment: Thanks, and it works. But what if the output image is a xml file? I check with xml file, but it does not work.

Comment: XML-files require a unique start and end-tag. You will need a specialized XML merge tool.